# How to specify image url in Bixby layout

Tags: bixby

I can't figure out how to link to specific image url in a Bixby layout template.

I tried specifying content > section > image > url > value in various expression formats but none worked.

This produces an empty section in the layout log.

```
 section {
      content {
         image {
             url ("#{value(image)}")
               }
    }
    }
  }
```

I want the image specified in the content object to appear.

If I hard code the image as url ("images/Shakespeare.jpg") for example it works, so there is something wrong with the way I am invoking the expression language.

Answer (score 3):

Solved: I needed to specify the URL property of the Image concept.

```
section {
      content {
         image {
             url ("#{value(image.url)}")
               }
    }
    }
  }
```